# Positioning button at the bottom of bootstrap well

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi so I am having trouble with the positioning of the button. I need the button to be at the bottom of the well but somehow I can't seem to position it there.

Here is what happened: the button ends up at the side of the image, but I need it to be at the bottom of the well
[image]

Here are my codes:

```
<div class="container">
<h2 class="center">CTTS Data</h2>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12" id="CTTSData">


    <script>
    $.ajax({
      url : "CR_Data/CTTS_Data.json",
      type : "post", 
      contentType:"application/json", 
      success : function(list){           
          var divCol  = "<div class='col-sm-4 col-md-4'>";
          var divWell = "<div class='well' style='position:relative'>";
          var divClose = "</div>";

          console.log(list);

            list.forEach(function(obj, index) {

            //console.log(obj); 

            var title     = "<h5>"      + obj.title    + "</h5>";
            var linkStart = "<a href='" + obj.imagePath + "' target='_blank'>" ;
            var image     = "<img class='thumbnailSmall' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='left' title='Click to open data' src='" 
                                + obj.imagePath + "' height='100%' width='100%'/>"
            var linkEnd   = "</a>";
            var linkFile  = "<a class='btn btn-danger' id='btnView' href='" + obj.filePath + "'>Open File</a>";

            var div = divCol    +
            divWell     +
            title       +
           // desc        +
            linkStart       +
            image       +
            linkEnd +
            linkFile +
            divClose +
            divClose;

           $("#CTTSData").append(div); // insert the div you've just created

           })
        }
    });
  </script>


  </div>
  </div>

</div>
<!-- /.container -->
```

CSS:

```
#btnView{
position: absolute;
margin-bottom:   20px;
}
```

Comment: Try removing the `position` CSS attribute. and make sure the button is being declared inside the well. if the button is for sure inside the well and is still not where you want it, add back the `position` attribute, but set it to `relative`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd enclose your button inside a bootstrap "row" container, like this:

```js
var divCol  = "<div class='col-sm-4 col-md-4'>";
var divWell = "<div class='well'>";
var divClose = "</div>";

var title     = "<h5> title </h5>";
var linkStart = "<a href='#' target='_blank'>" ;
var image     = "<img class='thumbnailSmall' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='left' title='Click to open data' src='path' height='100%' width='100%'/>"
var linkEnd   = "</a>";
var linkFile  = "<div class='row'><a class='btn btn-danger' id='btnView' href='#'>Open File</a></div>";

var div = divCol + divWell + title + linkStart + image + linkEnd + linkFile + divClose + divClose;

$("#CTTSData").append(div); // insert the div you've just created
```

```css
#btnView{
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h2 class="center">CTTS Data</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12" id="CTTSData">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /.container -->
```